# Access a text file from two applications at the same time

Tags: c#, labview

I have a c# program that updates a txt file at random time intervals, and a labview program that continuously checks the data in the txt file and checks it.

Can you guide me to a way to avoid collisions between those apps?

Comment: So one app is a reader and the other is a writer, correct? Both apps won't write to the file at the same time?

Comment: yes exactly. c# writes and labview reads,

Comment: In that case only managing the file locks should be necessary to mitigate any collisions. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with labview enough to provide a solid answer. I can only suggest looking into any options it provides regarding file locking.

Comment: @Mario  I was not aware Labview was not a C# app.

Comment: You can use Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out what type of share labview is using when it opens the file.

Comment: Communication between processes via text file is awkward and may lead to bad surprises, you should consider better inter-process communication stuff, like pipes or sockets

Answer (score 1):

LabVIEW has a deny access-vi. So you could block C# from writing while it reads. http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361E-01/glang/lock_range/ 
(Deny access - Read - Allow access)

I'd do the writing in C# with a try-catch loop, or something like that - but I'm no C#-expert.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use a named/global mutex

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf.aspx

Mutex's with the same name are seen as the same by all processes. You can use them to signal or lock.

Comment: Probably is not necessary, as one program is a writer, and the other one seems to be a reader, so both progams should be able to access the same file at the same time, as long as the correct FileShares are used.